# AWS Lambda: "End of stream" error when interacting with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an *AWS Lambda* function, which reads files from *S3*, converts them, and writes them to another *S3* bucket. Initially, the function works perfectly. However, sometimes, after repeated use, I get this error payload:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "End of stream",
    "errorType": "lambda_handler",
    "stackTrace": []
}
```

Why?

Comment: If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. So, most likely, the file you are reading is empty and therefore returns this error.

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge But it happens after repeatedly reading the same file, which is not empty.

Comment: Try to move the stream to position 0 before writing it then to see if it solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what technology you are using but do you dispose the streams properly and/or seek to position 0 on the stream before trying to read again?

Lambda function do not guarantee clean start up. It's actually a feature to re-use the previous container that may contains state from previous invocation

> After a Lambda function is executed, AWS Lambda maintains the
>   execution context for some time in anticipation of another Lambda
>   function invocation. In effect, the service freezes the execution
>   context after a Lambda function completes, and thaws the context for
>   reuse, if AWS Lambda chooses to reuse the context when the Lambda
>   function is invoked again. This execution context reuse approach has
>   the following implications:
>
> Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler
>   code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional
>   optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your
>   Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of
>   reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in
>   subsequent invocations. We suggest adding logic in your code to check
>   if a connection exists before creating one.
>
> Each execution context provides 512 MB of additional disk space in the
>   /tmp directory. The directory content remains when the execution
>   context is frozen, providing transient cache that can be used for
>   multiple invocations. You can add extra code to check if the cache has
>   the data that you stored. For information on deployment limits, see
>   AWS Lambda Limits.
>
> Background processes or callbacks initiated by your Lambda function
>   that did not complete when the function ended resume if AWS Lambda
>   chooses to reuse the execution context. You should make sure any
>   background processes or callbacks (in case of Node.js) in your code
>   are complete before the code exits.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html